# OnsenUI Navigator + React failed to navigate

Tags: reactjs, navigation, onsen-ui

I have been banging my head against wall for days due to the issue as mentioned in the title. I was trying to implement navigation function using Onsen UI and React. However after I click to navigate, the UI navigates to a blank page, and immediately goes back to the first page. Below is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Page, Navigator, Button, SearchInput } from "react-onsenui";

function EditorView() {
  return <Page>This is the editor page!</Page>;
}

function SearchBar() {
  return <SearchInput placeholder="Search" />;
}
const switchToEditorView = navigator => {
  navigator.pushPage({ component: EditorView, props: { key: "editorPage" } });
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Navigator
      renderPage={(route, navigator) => (
        <Page key={route.title}>
          <SearchBar />
          <Page className="custom_page_wrapper">
           <Button onClick={() => switchToEditorView(navigator)}>
            Click to navigate
           </Button>
          </Page>
        </Page>
      )}
      initialRoute={{ component: App, props: { key: "firstPage" } }}
     />
   );
 }
export default App;
```

And the codesandbox is here to play with : https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lichterman-okme5?file=/src/App.js:0-828

How to overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are rendering a constant page in navigator whereas you must render the page component that you pass like

```
import React from "react";
import { Page, Navigator, Button, SearchInput } from "react-onsenui";

function EditorView() {
  return <Page>This is the editor page!</Page>;
}

function SearchBar() {
  return <SearchInput placeholder="Search" />;
}
const switchToEditorView = navigator => {
  navigator.pushPage({ component: EditorView, props: { key: "editorPage" } });
};

function Main({ navigator, title, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Page key={title}>
      <SearchBar />
      Hello
      <Page className="custom_page_wrapper">
        <Button onClick={() => switchToEditorView(navigator)}>
          Click to navigate
        </Button>
      </Page>
    </Page>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Navigator
      renderPage={(route, navigator) => (
        <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.props} />
      )}
      initialRoute={{ component: Main, props: { key: "firstPage" } }}
    />
  );
}
export default App;
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-smoke-1qj7r?file=/src/App.js:0-927)**